# How would I activate a modal using JavaScript only for Mobile Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

OK So I need to detect if someone is using mobile and then politely ask them to rotate the screen so that it is a landscape window, not a vertical one.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser/13819253) for detecting a mobile browser.

Using Bootstrap, I would like to make a modal appear for to tell them to rotate the screen.

I also found this from the Bootstrap JavaScript guides:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
</button>
```

As you can see they use `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` to call forth the modal.  How would I go about implementing that so it runs when a Javascript value is returned?

Something like

```
if ( mobile == 1 ) {
    // open modal
else {
   // ignore modal (do nothing)
}
```

would suffice for the detection, but how would I go about the `//open modal` part?

jQuery can be used as well, if that helps anyone (removes some restrictions).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples of how to interact with Bootstrap modals in JavaScript can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. In short, it looks like you can programmatically call `$('#myModal').modal(options)` on an element to activate it as a modal dialog.